# Leitura de sequência de números separados por espaço

Tags: c

É necessário ler somente **uma linha** com um conjunto de números inteiros separados por espaço, cada item separado por espaço será inserido numa lista ligada: *1 41 2 15 6 7 87 4 2 1 9 0*

Lista seria algo como = `[1, 41, 2, 15, 6, 7, 87, 4, 2, 1, 9, 0]`

Exemplo:

```
$ gcc example.c -o example -g -Wall 
$ ./example 
1 41 2 15 6 7 87 4 2 1 9 0<enter>
```

O maior problema é que a quantidade de números que virão na entrada é indefinida, ou seja, a entrada também pode ser: *1 8 6*

```
Lista = [1, 8, 6]
```

Por a quantidade ser indefinida, eu pensei em duas soluções possíveis:

- a) `scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", sequenciaNumeros);`
- b) Usar `fgets`

Em ambos os casos, eu teria que o problema de declarar um vetor de caracteres enorme para garantir que não atinja o limite.

Se a quantidade fosse definida seria simples:

```
scanf("%d %d %d, &valor1, &valor2, &valor3)
```

É possível com o `scanf` pegar esta linha e conseguir manipular cada um dos números (que estão separados por espaço) para adicionar na lista, sabendo que a quantidade de números **pode variar**? A entrada é obrigatoriamente somente uma linha de um conjunto de números separados por espaço

Comment: tem outras possibilidades, como fazer 2 leituras, uma só contando os ítens, e outra alocando e capturando.

Comment: @Bacco É necessário fazer de uma vez a leitura, não é possível contar e depois ler.

Comment: É uma regra do enunciado? Seria bom por na pergunta tb. Sobre o que falou de alocar, vc nao precisa alocar um espaço imenso, pode ir alocando com sobra, e realocando se não couber. De 1 em 1 é muita alocação de bobeira, mas não precisa prever caberem todos.

Comment: @Bacco O enunciado possui várias páginas e regras, irá acabando fugir do escopo da pergunta. A entrada deve ser obrigatoriamente assim com uma linha só.

Comment: É que corre o risco de alguém responder e não satisfazer as regras, aí a pessoa perde tempo e não te serve. Seria bom ver se não tem mais nenhuma "pegadinha" dessas, e ao menos mencionar. Se eu tivesse parado pra te ajudar com código e vc me contasse isso depois, imagino que eu ia ficar bem descontente. Pode acontecer com outras pessoas. Se descrever os detalhes importantes todos, você vai ter respostas melhores.

Comment: A pergunta não está boa, talvez por ter um requisito artificial que não ajuda em nada ter um bom código. Por isso as respostas até agora mandam fazer de outra forma diferente do que está no enunciado (pelo menos o que dá para compreender dele). As respostas são boas para resolver o problema da maneira como todo mundo resolveria, só não resolvem da maneira pedida pela pergunta, que é uma maneira esquisita.

Comment: @bigown Editei novamente a pergunta. Não sei se a maneira da entrada é difícil de ser manipulada ou eu que estou acostumada com entradas simples.

Comment: Eu acho que a pergunta até está clara, o requisito é que não faz muito sentido, conforme o Bacco disse. Acho que em função disso as pessoas que resolveram responder preferiram não se atentar a ele por serem algo fora do comum e foram no que é intuitivo fazer.

Comment: Na verdade, o fato de a entrada estar em "uma linha" não muda nada quando a leitura é feita usando `scanf`.

Comment: Não sei se você entendeu o que eu chamei de duas leituras. Falo duas leituras dentro da string digitada uma vez só. A primeira contando quantos numeros, e a segunda lendo os valores. Isso dependendo de qual técnica for usada para ler, claro. Só faz sentido se tratar a linha como uma coisa só.

Comment: "Interpretando" os requisitos, o que provavelmente está sendo pedido é algo assim: "ler uma sequência de números inteiros separados por espaços etc...". No terminal, no exemplo dado acima, depois do <enter> (ou em lugar do <enter>) haveria um control-d ou control-z para terminar a leitura dos inteiros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você *pode* utilizar o `scanf()`, pois com ele é possível distinguir os números entre si.

Para resolver seu problema, uma forma possível é **ler um número por vez** e a cada leitura, alocar dinamicamente memória suficiente para leitura desse número, utilizando `malloc()`. Para isso você precisaria de uma estrutura que expanda seu tamanho dinamicamente. Com isso, evita-se o problema de:

1. Alocar estaticamente um vetor pequeno demais e não conseguir armazenar todos os dados.
2. Alocar estaticamente um vetor muito grande, disperdiçando espaço em memória.

Uma estrutura de dados que te auxilia nisso é uma [lista encadeada](http://www.ime.usp.br/~pf/algoritmos/aulas/lista.html). Uma alternativa pode ser um array com tamanho dinâmico.

De qualquer forma você precisa definir um identificador de fim. Algum caractere que vai ditar quando a sequência termina. Se for uma sequência de números inteiros, você pode usar um caractere negativo para indicar o fim da sequência. Por exemplo, `-1`. Ou [EOF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3764068/406110).

**Porém**, talvez caiba aqui a seguinte reflexão: é necessário que todos os números estejam na memória de uma vez só?

Um exemplo muito simples para ilustrar esse cenário é um **acumulador**.

**Cenário:** Imagine que seja solicitado um programa para somar todos os número que o usuário digitar.
**Solução:** Uma abordagem é guardar todos na memória e depois iterar neles, somando-os. Uma abordagem mais simples seria, apenas fazer um acumulador:

`soma = soma + numero_da_entrada;`

Espero ter ajudado!

**Edição 1**: Aparentemente, você pode usar o retorno de `scanf()` para saber quando não há mais números a serem lidos:

```
int numero;
while(scanf("%d", &numero) == 1) { // scanf retorna 1 quando a leitura for bem sucedida
    printf("%d", numero);
}
```

**Edição 2**: Para ler a linha inteira e parar quando pressionar enter:

```
int numero;
char proxChar;
while(scanf("%d%c", &numero, &proxChar) == 2) { 
        printf("%d", numero);
        if(proxChar == '\n') break; 
}
```

Comment: O maior problema é: Como ler e distinguir todos os números de uma linha só com scanf? Não é possível ler um por vez com um laço for. Por exemplo: enviar 1 e dar enter, enviar 6 e dar enter etc.

Comment: Quando você liz de uma linha só, o que você quer dizer com isso? Se for de `stdin` não existe o conceito de linha. Neste caso, `scanf` vai entender espaços e quebras de linha como separadores de números, caso você use a máscara `%d`.

Comment: Pergunta editada

Comment: A resposta ainda se aplica.

Comment: O scanf irá guardar a linha inteira, correto? Se sim, como irei dar o malloc sendo que já terá estourado o tamanho? Se não, como irei ler número por número sem pedir para o usuário digitar novamente? Não ficou bem claro para mim como será a manipulação do scanf

Comment: O `scanf("%d", ...)` **não** irá guardar a linha inteira! Se você envolver o `scanf()` em um loop `while`, em cada chamada ele vai te retorna o próximo inteiro, até que não haja mais nenhum.

Comment: Obrigada, sempre me acostumei com fazer leituras "normais" do scanf e nem ao menos sabia o seu retorno.

Answer (score 1):

Leia apenas um número por vez. O resultado de scanf vai ser então 1 se a leitura foi bem sucedida, ou zero se não conseguiu, e neste caso a linha foi lida completamente.

Para cada número lido, aloque espaço dinâmicamente com malloc.
Use uma lista encadeada para guardar os números lidos.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) para pegar a entrada e [`strtok`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) para quebrar em partes:

```
char entrada[100];   // Para obter até 100 caracteres da entrada
int * elementos[10]; // Array com capacidade para 10 elementos
int i = 0;

int tamanhoArray = sizeof elementos / sizeof(int);

if(fgets(entrada, sizeof entrada, stdin) != NULL) {
    for (char *pedaco = strtok(entrada, " "); pedaco != NULL; pedaco = strtok(NULL, " ")) {

        // Se atingir a capacidade do array
        if (i >= tamanhoArray) {
            puts("Não foi possível adicionar mais itens na lista!");
            break;
        }
        elementos[i++] = pedaco;
    }

    for (int n = 0; n < tamanhoArray; ++n) {    
        printf("Indice [%d] = %s\n", n, elementos[n]);
    }
}
```

<kbd>[Ver **DEMO**](http://ideone.com/gRR1kQ)</kbd>

Se você preferir criar o `array` com tamanho baseado na quantidade de espaços:

```
char entrada[100];  // Para obter até 100 caracteres da entrada
int qtdEspacos = 1;
int i = 0;

if(fgets(entrada, sizeof entrada, stdin) != NULL) {
    char *ptr = entrada;

    while((ptr = strchr(ptr, ' ')) != NULL) { // Se encontrou espaço
        qtdEspacos++;
        ptr++;
    }

    // Cria o array com tamanho baseado na quantidade de espaços na string
    int * elementos[qtdEspacos];

    for (char *pedaco = strtok(entrada, " "); pedaco != NULL; pedaco = strtok(NULL, " ")) {
        elementos[i++] = pedaco;
    }

    for (int n = 0; n < qtdEspacos; ++n) {    
        printf("Indice [%d] = %s\n", n, elementos[n]);
    }
}
```

<kbd>[Ver **DEMO**](http://ideone.com/1wplR4)</kbd>